# How to trigger a function in an Ionic Capacitor App as soon as the screen gets unlocked

Tags: android, ionic-framework, capacitor, capacitor-plugin

How can I trigger a function in my Ionic Capacitor App as soon as the screen gets unlocked, even if the app is not active or started?

I could not find any solution in the capacitor docs or capacitor plugins.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The devices OS will not allow you to do that due to security reasons. Maybe with a native app you can but as far as hybrid goes, no way.